# OS X calling convention return value

Tags: macos, calling-convention, disassembly

I've seen a gdb disassembly output of a main function that does nothing particular and it looks like this:

```
1  push    %rbp
2  mov     %rsp, %rbp
3  sub     $0x10,%rsp
4  movl    $0x0, -0x8(%rbp)    ;
5  mov     -0x8(%rbp), %eax    ;
6  mov     %eax, -0x4(%rbp)    ;
7  mov     -0x4(%rbp), %eax    ;
8  add     $0x10, %rsp
9  pop     %rbp
10 retq
```

I'm not a Mac user, but I'm curious, what are exactly the lines from 4 to 7 doing? .Shouldn't be something like this:

```
push    %rbp
mov     %rsp, %rbp
sub     $0x10, %rsp
xor     %eax, %eax
add     $0x10, %rsp
pop     %rbp
retq
```

***Note***: please feel free to improve the question title, I couldn't find a better one.

Comment: This is unoptimized code; if you compile it with optimization, the generated code will likely be just a `xor %eax, %eax; retq`.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of this assembly code, looks like you have a 64 bits machine.

```
 4  movl    $0x0, -0x8(%rbp)    ;
 5  mov     -0x8(%rbp), %eax    ;
 6  mov     %eax, -0x4(%rbp)    ;
 7  mov     -0x4(%rbp), %eax    ;
```

They are correct instructions. the `%rbp` register here contains reference to the `Stack segment`. The notation `-08x(%rbp)` refers to a memory location, particularly the 8th index from the stack pointer. 
So then lines 4 - 5 say that:

```
4 put 0 in the 8th index of the stack segment
5 put the value of the 8th index of the stack segment in %eax
```

Same thing for lines 6 - 7.
If I'm not wrong, the initial program is made of only assignements...